# Yii2 Dropdown value dependent show/hide text field

Tags: php

YII2 has two field dropdownlist(relationship_status) and text input field(spouse_name). If the married is seected in dropdown list then only the spouse name text field should be appeared.

Comment: so use javascript/jquery to show/hide field based on dropdown value.

Answer (score 0):

**I was trying to make it like this way.**

> ```
> <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
>
> <div id="marriage">
>   <?= $form->field($model, 'marriage_status')->dropDownList([ 'married' => 'Married', 'unmarried' => 'Unmarried' ], ['prompt' =>
> ```
>
> 'Marriage Status']) ?>
>
> field($model, 'spouse_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>        
>       
>           isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn
>   btn-primary']) ?>
>
> ```
> <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
> ```
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){     $("#spouse").hide();
> $('#marriage').on('change', function() {
>   if ( $(event.target).val() == 'married')
>   {
>     $("#spouse").show();
>   }
>   else{
>       $("#spouse").hide();
>   }        
> }); });
> ```